# Why using cursors in PL/SQl ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm a beginner at PL/SQL, and during studying the course I saw `CURSOR` 
and I want to know why we should use it, and when? 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a **SELECT** and it returns more than one row you can't save the rows in a **variable**, so you'll have to use a **CURSOR**. If you are familiar with programming a **CURSOR** is something like an **Array**.
So if you do a **SELECT** and save the results in a variable like in the code:

```
SELECT id INTO v_id FROM table;
```

and if more than one row is returned, you cant save the rows in the variable **v_id**, and a **TOO_MANY_ROWS** Exception will be thrown.
Reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: very useful, i understood when you tald me about Array, it's same principle :)

Comment: @Arlind I have doubt If store procedures returns the result in multiset then what is the difference between using cursors over store procedures.?

Comment: @Kamini you have to understand that cursors are something different from store procedures you cannot compare them. Store Procedure is a program. Cursor is a holder that you use for for your programs data.

Comment: @Arlind Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you've seen Oracle's FOR ... IN (SELECT ...) ... LOOP ... END LOOP statement, that's using an implicit cursor.

The reason to use the explicit cursor method is that you can do more things with the cursor, such as BULK COLLECT which can greatly improve your processing performance in many, but not all, situations.  That greater control (beyond just doing BULK COLLECT) is helpful as you develop more-elaborate processes.

Good luck on your journey into Oracle.  I've been using it for 14 years and am a big fan.